# How to Use Mathematic Equations as Filters in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using the SQLAlchemy ORM to construct the MySQL queries in my application, and am perfectly able to add basic filters to the query, like so:

```
query = meta.Session.query(User).filter(User.user_id==1)
```

Which gives me something basically equivalent to this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 1
```

My question is how I would integrate some basic MySQL math functions into my query.  So, say for instance I wanted to get users near a certain latitude and longitude.  So I need to generate this SQL ($mylatitude and $mylongitude are the static latitude and longitude I'm comparing against):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE SQRT(POW(69.1 * (latitude - $mylatitude),2) + POW(53.0 * (longitude - $mylongitude),2)) < 5
```

Is there a way I can incorporate these functions into a query using the SQLAlchemy ORM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use the query builder interface and the `func` SQL function constructor to abstract the calculation as a function. This way you can use it freely with aliases or joins.

```
User.coords = classmethod(lambda s: (s.latitude, s.longitude))

def calc_distance(latlong1, latlong2):
    return func.sqrt(func.pow(69.1 * (latlong1[0] - latlong2[0]),2)
                   + func.pow(53.0 * (latlong1[1] - latlong2[1]),2))

meta.Session.query(User).filter(calc_distance(User.coords(), (my_lat, my_long)) < 5)
```

Comment: Can't get this to work. Seems like `s.latitude` and `s.longitude` returns the class method's latitude and longitude instead of the instance's latitude and longitude. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 6):

You can use literal SQL in your filter, see here: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html?highlight=text#using-literal-sql

For example:

```
clause = "SQRT(POW(69.1 * (latitude - :lat),2) + POW(53.0 * (longitude - :long),2)) < 5"
query = meta.Session.query(User).filter(clause).params(lat=my_latitude, long=my_longitude)
```

Comment: This is just what I'm looking for.  One question though: if I'm joining in a bunch of other tables, how would I ensure that latitude matched up with User.latitude and not some other latitude field?  Since my User object might link to a table called xx_users_1 in the actual query, is there a way to put in the table name `xx_users_1`.`latitude`?

Comment: You can try to force the table name to a particular value by using `sqlalchemy.orm.aliased` (perhaps something like `query(aliased(User, 'xx_users'))`. I've never used it though.

Comment: As for SQLAlchemy==1.4.51, you also need to wrap clause string with `text` from `sqlalchemy.sql` to be able to run it.