# How to pass a model parameter in a filter condition in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to handle the database of a Flask webapp that I am currently working on. As a function of the website, I want users to be able to search for other users with location and radius from that specified location as parameters. So naturally, not knowing much about SQLAlchemy, I tried with this expression:

```
profiles = User.query.filter(sqrt(abs(User.latitude - location.latitude)**2 + abs(User.longitude - location.longitude)**2) <= radius)
```

*Explanation: I want to return all the users located at a distance within the specified radius from the specified location.*

However, it then gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
   return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
 File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
   response = self.handle_exception(e)
 File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
   reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
   raise value
 File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
   response = self.full_dispatch_request()
 File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
   rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
 File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
   reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
   raise value
 File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
   rv = self.dispatch_request()
 File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
   return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
 File "C:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\start\app\routes.py", line 136, in explore
   profiles = User.query.filter_by(sqrt(abs(User.latitude - location.latitude)**2 + abs(User.longitude - location.longitude)**2) <= radius)
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'BinaryExpression'
```

**How will I be able to pass a model parameter inside an equation as a condition in a query search like this one?**

## Edit

After the suggestion from *frost-nzcr4*, I tried to go with the `@hybrid_method` decorator, since that seems to be the one that fits the best in my case.

(I came to that conclusion by reading the docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html)

Therefore, I added this to my model:

```
@hybrid_method
def is_nearby(self, latitude, longitude, radius):
    return sqrt((self.latitude - latitude)**2 + (self.longitude - longitude)**2) <= radius
```

(I also removed the `abs()` functions inside of the expression, because the squaring already returns an exclusively positive value..)

And this to my route instead of the old expression:

```
profiles = User.query.filter(User.is_nearby(latitude=location.latitude, longitude=location.longitude, radius=radius))
```

(FYI I then saved my code, updated my database and restarted the flask server)

I tried the query search again, and...
I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\start\app\routes.py", line 134, in explore
    profiles = User.query.filter(User.is_nearby(latitude=location.latitude, longitude=location.longitude, radius=radius))
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\start\app\models.py", line 64, in is_nearby
    return sqrt((self.latitude - latitude)**2 + (self.longitude - longitude)**2) <= radius
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'BinaryExpression' and 'int'
```

The location variable isn't containing a sqlalchemy model. It's an object from [the Geopy Python library](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#). However, its dependencies `.latitude` and `.longitude` are both just floats. As an example it could be defined like this:

```
location = geolocator.geocode("NYC, New York, USA")
```

And this is my User model with its two dependencies relevant to this problem:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    ...
    latitude = db.Column(db.Float, index=True)
    longitude = db.Column(db.Float, index=True)
    ...
```

**Why is it that these properties of the model can't be applied specific operands ie. squaring within a condition in a query search? And how can I get around it in my case?**

PS

Thank you so much for commenting **frost-nzcr4**. It means a lot!

## Edit 2

Ok, so now after another suggestion from *frost-nzcr4*, I changed the `is_nearby` method to this:
(Here `func` is referencing to `from sqlalchemy import func`)

```
@hybrid_method
def is_nearby(self, latitude, longitude, radius):
    return func.sqrt(func.pow(self.latitude - latitude, 2) + func.pow(self.longitude - longitude, 2)) <= radius
```

Also, the query search statement is now written like this:

```
profiles = User.query.filter(User.is_nearby(latitude=location.latitude, longitude=location.longitude, radius=radius)).all()
```

And it works! It gets rid of the previous error.. But then comes another..:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: sqrt

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\start\app\routes.py", line 135, in explore
    profiles = User.query.filter(User.is_nearby(latitude=location.latitude, longitude=location.longitude, radius=radius)).all()
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3161, in all
    return list(self)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3317, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3342, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 383, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 128, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "c:\users\frederik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: sqrt
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.name AS user_name, user.location AS user_location, user.latitude AS user_latitude, user.longitude AS user_longitude, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.password_hash AS user_password_hash
FROM user
WHERE sqrt(pow(user.latitude - ?, ?) + pow(user.longitude - ?, ?)) <= ?]
[parameters: (55.8125143, 2, 12.4687513, 2, '10')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

It seems like there's no equivalent to the Math module's square root function inside of `sqlalchemy.func`.

**If there is, what is it called then? And if there isn't, what can I then do?**

Comment: Check for decorator `@hybrid_property` and use all functions from `sqlaclhemy.func`

Comment: Describe here your `location` model.

Comment: Did you try `sqlalchemy.func.pow(self.latitude - latitude, 2)`?

Comment: Again again, Thank you! The squaring now works, I think, but `sqlalchemy.func` doesn't seem to contain a function equivalent to the Math module's `sqrt()`. The question is now updated with the error that I'm getting. (I hope this is the last step!)

Comment: `sqlalchemy.func` does not contain any functions, it is a factory of sorts for producing SQL function expressions (datastructures later compiled to actual SQL). You can use it to produce just about any function expression, for example `func.xyzzy()`. The problem is that SQLite does not provide the math functions out of the box, but it is easy to register those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595050/python-sqlalchemy-filter-query-by-great-circle-distance and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061014/accessing-table-variables-in-flask-sqlalchemy-query-during-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a bit complex:

1. Describe the logic via `@hybrid_method`/`@hybrid_property`.
2. Use `sqlalchemy.func` for `pow`, `sqrt` and so on.
3. Be sure that your DB backend have implemented these functions.

In your case `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: sqrt` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731982/5274713. In worst case you've to use plain SQL expression as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2002448/5274713

Comment: Yo thank you so much for helping me out! By going through your links, I noticed that in order to avoid having to download support for `sqrt()` and `pow()` I could just write the`is_nearby` method's return statement like this: `return (self.latitude - latitude)*(self.latitude - latitude)+(self.longitude - longitude)*(self.longitude - longitude) <= radius*radius`

Comment: On a second thought, I'll probably need to implement something like [the Haversine formula](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), but that's another question ;)